# How to get a clean htaccess redirection erasing the url parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am struggling with my .htaccess to have some clean output.
I have the link:

```
http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/aclk?sa=L&ai=C6L7ifLUkUqDLHMLk8AOStYCIA_Te4_sDAAAQASAAUN-djNP4_____wFg-5n5gogKggEXY2EtcHViLTg5Mzg3NzAyNjUxMTc1MTXIAQLgAgCoAwGqBIIBT9D5uNN_cW90jRk-X4AGFEvVUc3uXa1gEO0EVdqEJdFyscP9bI0bJppGDdfQaHLHr7d8O0OCuV7YjpyvQksPhaVEtZ5itfPvt-VGEgDXYEYXKaUOI7F5keBCdOwMtKYRQ_idwvU18o5TiLhZlIn3YEPi84R2VHemIxwO1Nrffrubl-AEAaAGFA&num=0&sig=AOD64_0k1kyhYI-Pe4qbk_16igqgBYXrqA&client=ca-pub-8938770265117515&adurl=http://THAT_ADVERTISMENT
```

When I click on it I would like to be redirected to:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
```

My .htaccess is:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^googleads.g.doubleclick.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^adclick.g.doubleclick.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://stackoverflow.com/ [R=301,L]
```

The issue here is the redirected url is like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/?sa=L&ai=C6L7ifLUkUqDLHMLk8AOStYCIA_Te4_.....
```

I would like to have a clean output without the parameters after the first slash. I read some stuff and I test my htaccess with an online tester.

Please excuse me if my question is too candid, maybe I have read too fast my documentation. Anyway, thank you in advance for your help/solution/link :).

Comment: You can only redirect your domain you cannot redirect 3rd party domains

Comment: Someone answered my question but what he wrote is not visible anymore, don't know why.
edit: is usefull for someone, adding a "?" at the end of the wanted url will do the job just fine. In this case I can redirect to 3rd party domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.stackoverflow.com/? [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect to this 3rd party